# Calling finance.yahoo api using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I want to send http request for fetching finance.yahoo stock data with url like : http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GAIL.NS+BPCL.NS+%5ENSEI&f=snl1hgp which returns a csv file. I want to read the response data and fill it in a listview using Javascript or JQuery mobile. None of the links I referred helped me.

I tried using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv",
    data: "s=GAIL.NS+BPCL.NS+%5ENSEI&f=snl1hgp",
    dataType: "text/csv",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify('data is :' + data));
    }
});
```

I get blank data as alert.
Any sample code or useful link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is the request is cross domain. There is another question about this here:

[Cross-Domain get CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755038/cross-domain-get-csv-file)

and another answer here :[Yahoo JSONP Ajax Request Wrapped in callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567119/yahoo-jsonp-ajax-request-wrapped-in-callback-function)

and a working example here: [Displaying ajax results from yahoo finance using underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575323/displaying-ajax-results-from-yahoo-finance-using-underscore-js)

Here is a working jsfiddle which makes a jsonp request to d.yimg.com to get the data  http://jsfiddle.net/gp6zL/

```
    YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback = function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    };
    var query;
    query = 'Google';
    if (query.length > 0) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc",
            data: {
                query: query
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",
        });
    }
```

Comment: sorry. It was a type mistake. I have edited my post. alert(data) also returns blank

Comment: I referred to your links. but now i get :null as output

Answer (score 1):

I try to take jQuery out of the equation. The following code will work as long as you [whitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) "finance.yahoo.com".

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GAIL.NS+BPCL.NS+%5ENSEI&f=snl1hgp", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }
}
request.send();
```